# Apache Bad Request through Cloudflare 2053 SSL port

Tags: debian-wheezy, cloudflare, apache2

I have CloudFlare serving traffic on port 443, connecting to my vHost on port 2053. The connection to CloudFlare succeeds, but the server sends a 400 response.

The idea of this port is to serve a private / hidden control panel through that port just like any other SSL vHost running on 443.

vHost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ServerName sub.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias sub.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub.mydomain.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /var/www/sub.mydomain.com/logs/error.log 
    CustomLog /var/www/sub.mydomain.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache2.conf:
http://pastebin.com/AvQMyytk

Comment: You need to post your configuration and logs if you want help. Please edit your original post, which I've cleaned up a lot to make it clearer and more professional.

Comment: Edited. I'm new to StackOverflow, my bad :P

Comment: SO is for professional questions and discussions. Emoticons are not generally used. You've said you're listening on port 2053 but your virtual host is listening on port 80. Either your text is wrong or your configuration is clearly incorrect. You need to post logs showing the error.

Comment: I just changed Port 80 to 2053, the config was from when I gave up on fixing it, Sorry. The 400 error is coming up when i browse to the said domain at port 2053, the vHost is listening on 2053 now. The error itself is just 'The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port'.

Comment: That error basically tells you the answer.